# AngularJS form error on submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Based on my form.json I have a form which should have a validation and a fake submission.

- Firstly I should fix this **error**: `fnPtr is not a function`
- Then **submit** the form to another mocked API endpoint which returns true or false, can I use this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http ? if yes how?

*So when I submit the form.. I need to make an AJAX request which will package up the results from the form… send it to the endpoint… and that endpoint I think should give me some data back*.

[Demo in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fK6NL8G6zgaTp7d4zM4P?p=preview)

JS

```
var myApp=angular.module('CreateApp', []);

myApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('form.json').success(function(response) {
    $scope.result = response;
    console.log($scope.fields);
  });



  $http.get('form.json').success(function(response) {
    $scope.result = response;
    var fields = response.fields;
    $scope.richestClub = fields.answer.options[0].value;
    console.log($scope.richestClub);
    console.log($scope.fields);
  });

});
```

HTML

```
<my-form ng-app="CreateApp" ng-controller="mainController">

      <form ng-submit="userForm()" name="userForm" novalidate>
          <fieldset>
            <div ng-repeat="field in result.fields">
              <label for="{{field.type}}">{{field.label}}</label>

              <input ng-if="field.type != 'radio'"
                     name="{{field.name}}"
                     ng-required="{{field.required}}"
                     value="{{options.value}}" 
                     type="{{field.type}}" />

              <div ng-if="field.type == 'radio'">
                <div ng-repeat="option in field.options">

                  <input type="{{field.type}}"
                         name="{{field.name}}"
                         ng-required="{{field.required}}"
                         ng-model="richestClub"
                         value="{{option.value}}" />{{option.label}}
                </div>
              </div>

              <form-error ng-show="{{!!field.errorMessages.required}}">{{field.errorMessages.required}}</form-error>
              <form-error ng-show="{{!!field.errorMessages.invalid}}">{{field.errorMessages.invalid}}</form-error>
            </div>
          </fieldset>

         <button type="submit"
                 ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid"
                 ng-click="onSubmit(userForm)"> Submit </button>
        </form>

    </my-form>
```

Answer (score 0):

- > Firstly I should fix this error: fnPtr is not a function

You should define the `userForm` and `onSubmit` function in controller which is used in HTML. Also you shouldn't write same form name as `ng-submit` name

[plunkr demo without any function error](http://plnkr.co/edit/XajwzqaIUPA7twrN72xN?p=preview)

- > Then submit the form to another mocked API endpoint which returns true or false, can I use this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http ?

Yes, try this way

```
$http.post(url,data).then(function(response){
//you code
})
```

Comment: can I ask you why the radio buttons choice are not validated or not called once I  submit?

Comment: That, Response, shouldn't be integrated to the validation to?

Comment: for GET $http.get(url,data).then(function(response){

})

Comment: @Sreemat would you please check the plunker and see if works?

Comment: @user3699998 Yes,u can see that data in console.

Comment: @user3699998 Check out this link create a object for your form and and while submitting pass the object  in html and in js it will be easy to retrieve https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: @Sreemat but not I get confused with my js file. what code do I need?

Comment: would you be able to check this please http://plnkr.co/edit/Srj7fleeDpBX1XxspGNp?p=preview

Comment: Can you explain which not working before checking the plnkr @user3699998 Or just give the function that you want to do

Comment: @Sreemat the issue here is that html should get the json correctly in order to validate  and submit. I don't thing works correctly.